# Laravel5のPluralizerに関して

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.1を使用しております。

既存のデータベースを使いLaravelでWebサイトをリニューアルしようとしております。

"persons"というテーブルを使いたいので、Personというモデルを作成、アクセスしようとしたところ、

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'データベース名.people' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `people`)

というエラーが出てきました。
調べたところ、Pluralizerが働いているようなので、コアコードを削除を試みましたが、削除箇所がわからず..、またコアをいじらずpersonsテーブルを使う方法があれば試したいのですが..

(具体的にはInflector.phpのperson関連を削除してみても変わらず、といったところです。
また、postsテーブルなどにはアクセス出来ております。）

初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、ご存知の方がいればご教示いただければ幸いです。m(_ _)m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Laravelのドキュメント](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)によると、モデルではテーブルを指定することが可能です！

秘訣はLaravelのドキュメントの「[`Defining Models`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models) `-> Table Names`」というところで見つかります。特に`protected $table = 'persons';`という文を通して、自分のテーブルを指定することができそうです。

超簡単なモデル例：

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'persons';
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！ドキュメントに書いてあったとは盲点です。
ご教示いただいた方法でアクセスすることができました。

大変助かりました。これからドキュメントを再確認して参ります。